# showing bata in persnalize datatable

Tags: php, codeigniter

*I have in my model there function, all this function is used for displaying the frequence of  travel ''voyage'' of trucks ''camion'', the code work but my problem is about the view in codeigniter, i would like to show the result of my requete like in the image

[image]

```
function display_frequenceVoyageTrajet()
{ 
            $query=$this->db->query("SELECT trajet_Voyage, imm_Camion,year(dateBL_Voyage) AS Year, CASE month(dateBL_Voyage)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Janvier'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Fevrier'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Mars'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Avril'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Mai'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Juin'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Juillet'
        WHEN 8 THEN 'Août'
        WHEN 9 THEN 'Steptembre'
        WHEN 10 THEN 'Octobre'
        WHEN 11 THEN 'Novembre'
        WHEN 12 THEN 'Decembre' 
        END AS  `monthname`,MONTH(dateBL_Voyage) `month`, COUNT(*) as frequence FROM voyage GROUP BY trajet_Voyage,imm_Camion,year(dateBL_Voyage), DATE_FORMAT(`dateBL_Voyage`, '%M') ORDER BY MONTH(dateBL_Voyage),year(dateBL_Voyage)");
    return $query->result();}





function display_frequenceVoyageTrajet1()
{ 
        $query1=$this->db->query("SELECT  imm_Camion FROM camion");
    return $query1->result();
}





function display_frequenceVoyageTrajet2()
{ 
        $query2=$this->db->query("SELECT  COUNT(*) as total FROM camion");
    return $query2->result();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how is it different from your image?

Comment: [this is what i tried, the result is correct but i need to display it like the image in my post][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztCCf.png